# how to get max from aggregation result, without getting all values

Tags: elasticsearch-aggregation

My Aggregation query is returning me thousands of results inside the bucket, but I want only top one in my response(I have addedd orderby: desc in query)

```
"aggs": {
        "uri": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "field1",
                "size": 1,
                "order": {
                    "_count": "desc"
                }
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "datetime": {
                    "date_histogram": {
                        "field": "@datetime",
                        "interval": "1s",
                        "min_doc_count": 0,
                        "order": {
                            "_count": "desc"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Output is

```
"buckets": [
  {
    "key_as_string": "2019-07-20T02:57:26.000+05:30",
    "key": 1563571646000,
    "doc_count": 522
  },
  {
   "key_as_string": "2019-07-20T03:13:05.000+05:30",
   "key": 1563572585000,
   "doc_count": 504
  },
  {
   "key_as_string": "2019-07-20T03:13:16.000+05:30",
   "key": 1563572596000,
   "doc_count": 500
  },
.
.
.
.
.
]
```

whereas my expected output is

```
"buckets": [{
    "key_as_string": "2019-07-20T02:57:26.000+05:30",
    "key": 1563571646000,"doc_count": 522
}]
```

how can I achieve this??